# In App Purchasing API

Tags: php, iphone, objective-c, in-app-purchase

I'm researching how to do In App purchasing using the iPhone SDK. Is there any open source code out there regarding this? Both client-side and server side? Apples docs are great but nothing is better than already functioning code to help the learning curve.

I am not looking for http://urbanairship.com . I'm looking for server code I could put on my own server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ask you to look at the [MKStoreKit](http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/iphone-tutorial-%E2%80%93-in-app-purchases/) library for Xcode (also available [GitHub repository](https://github.com/mugunthkumar/MKStoreKit)). It's a full working tool that will help you build an efficient client/server-side in-app-purchasing-powered application.

It surely worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

ChinaPaul -

I don't have the server side code that you're looking for, but I put up some sample code for using the StoreKit and including In App Purchasing in your iPhone App.

Hope this helps some. Don't hesitate to contact me through the site or directly with questions.

Find the sample here: [The App Tree - In App Purchase - Free Sample](http://www.theapptree.com/samples)

Comment: I just want to say, after a year, that this was very helpful in my project. But I can't mark the question answered because it isn't server code. Still thanks